# How to convert dots to commas in mathmode?

Tags: math-mode, punctuation

For my study of physics I have to do various lab reports. Normally I just process all my data using `python`, `gnuplot` or Mathematica and copy it from there to my TeX document. Unfortunately all these applications use the `.` (dot) as a decimal seperator. Because I study in Germany the german standard says that I have to use `,` (comma) as the decimal seperator. In most cases the supervisors of the lab are forgiving, but one of them told me to redo my whole lab report because of this. Now I don't want to search all the 15 pages to replace all dots with commas. I could have used a [regular expression](http://xkcd.org/1171/) but this still implied editing the whole file.

Comment: Although it is very interesting (and quite useful), it does not pose a question. This is a Q&A site. So a better way would be to ask "How to change `.` to `,` in mathmode". Then you can yourself answer that question. Please see the discussion: http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4/asking-a-question-and-answering-it-yourself-straight-away/5#5

Comment: No problem. I just didn't find that question here so I thought it might be helpful for others if I share my solution.

Comment: Great! This is much better! :) Also there is no need to sign of with your name. I have deleted that.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It is perhaps less intrusive just to change the mathcode of `.` rather than globally define an active `.` to be a comma.

```
\mathcode`\.=\mathcode`\,
```

Would define `.` to be like `,` (as in the self-answer) If you want the . to be mathord so it os not followed by a thin space then you could use

```
\DeclareMathSymbol{.}{\mathord}{letters}{"3B}
```

Comment: ``\mathcode`\.=\numexpr\mathcode`\,-"6000\relax`` `;-)`

Answer (score 15):

Whether in math mode or not, I will

- always use `\num` from `siunitx` for any numerical literals,
- always use `.` for the decimal marker in the decimal literals,
- but later set the global setting in the preamble to specify the decimal marker for the rendered output.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{
    %output-decimal-marker={,}% just uncomment if you want to use comma as the decimal marker!
}

\begin{document}
$\num{3.14}$ is not the value of $\pi$, \num{2.718281828} is not the value of $e$.
\end{document}
```

This mechanism makes your document portable!

Comment: I hate using `,` as the decimal marker because comma separated list becomes ambiguous. For example, what does `(1,2,3,4)` mean in the context of 3-dimensional point? In scientific purposes, we have to use `.` for the decimal marker!

Comment: I totally agree with you on that. The problem is that I needed the supervisors signature for this lab report. And in the lab not the truth is correct but what is signed by the supervisors :(

Comment: @GarbageCollector This is not about hating, but about national typography rules. In Czech language, the rules are similar, and you get easily used to `;` as a list seperator. With the proper spacing (tight around `,` and loose after `;`) the result is just ok.

Comment: @tohecz: The typographic rules might be adopted without the scientific standards in mind. The countries using `,` as the decimal marker should change the rule because there is no benefit to keep. :-)

Comment: The countries using non-metric measurng systems should change it ;-)

Comment: @Tobi: Does `,` as the decimal marker conform to the standard metric system?

Comment: @GarbageCollector No, but the imperial units are confusing (and ambiguous). In my opinion more than using `,;` instead of `.,`. Since this discussion starts to be off-topic, this is my last comment here.

Comment: @GarbageCollector: ORLY;)?  Imho, decimal comma is actually better than decimal point, since in handwriting the point is more easy to lose.  Having a more visible sign is a significant benefit.  (And btw, in print, since after the decimal comma there's no space and after the separator comma there's a thin space, you don't even have to resort to a semicolon.)

Comment: @mbork: A funny grammar arises, for example: "The 3 numbers are 1,2; 3,4; and 5,6; They are in decimal form." Let's compare it with "The 3 numbers are 1.2, 3.4, and 5.6; They are in decimal form."

Answer (score 7):

### The Trick

```
\mathcode`\.="8000
{\catcode`\.=\active
\gdef.{,}}
```

### Explanation

But what does this do? I'll try to explain what the above code is doing. If I'm wrong please correct me.

`` \mathcode`\.="8000 `` makes the comma "active" in mathmode, i.e. everytime the compiler runs over a comma code is executed instead of a comma being typeset. `` {\catcode`\.=\active \gdef.{,}} `` is the code that gets executed in the beginning, where `` \catcode`\.=\active `` makes `.` active and then defines `\gdef.{,}` which substitutes the `.` with a `,`. That's it!

Keep in mind that now EVERY `.` in mathmode is replaced with a `,`. The code I presented doesn't care if the `.` you wrote is a decimal seperator of a full stop. If you want to type a full stop consider using `\text{.}`, or define yourself a macro.

Comment: I don't think you need `\makeat...` here ;) Your explanation of the meaning of that command is incorrect, see here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8351/what-do-makeatletter-and-makeatother-do

Comment: I hope my edit fixes the mistake you reported. Thanks.

Comment: Yes thanks I deleted my comment (I prefer my answer though:-)

Comment: Btw, shouldn't it be `\gdef.{{,}}` so that it is an ordinary atom therefore tightly spaced?

Comment: I accomplished this by loading [icomma](http://ctan.org/pkg/icomma), but your solution also sounds good, thank you.