# Decimal comma: extract one feature from babel-spanish

Tags: math-mode, punctuation, babel

`\usepackage[spanish]{babel}` makes `$12.34$` to print "12,34", not "12.34". It doesn't change dot to comma if one says for example `$x.y$`.

Can I use only that feature from babel package, and still use finnish hyphenation, typography etc?

Comment: Does http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/97571/how-to-convert-dots-to-commas-in-mathmode help?

Comment: rather than doing complicated things with active characters, perhaps adding some mark-up to the source is a simpler option: `$\np {12.34}$`, with the `\np` macro from the [numprint package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/numprint), which is configurable (`\npdecimalsign{,}` for example; see the doc page 14). You also need option `np` to use the abbreviated form rather than `\numprint`.

Comment: Cgnieder: not really, think about `If $x=y$ we have \[ f(x)=f(y). \]`. Of course there are solutions, like `x \approx 12{,}34`. But babel-spanish -style would be easiest way.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would suggest you use the `siunitx` package and set the comma as decimal point by `\sisetup{output-decimal-marker = {,}}`.

Using this package will also allow you to use some other very nice features that you'll find handy, such as 3-number separators, SI units, D columns (when dealing with tables full of numbers) and much more!

Take a look at the `siunitx` package [documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/siunitx/siunitx.pdf).

Also, according to section 4.1 of the "[Estilo spanish para el sistema babel](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/babel-contrib/spanish/spanish.pdf)", you can set the use of comma as decimal point by `\decimalcomma`.

In other words, load the babel package like this:  `\usepackage[spanish,finnish]{babel}` (so your main language is finnish) and then set the comma as decimal point by `\decimalcomma`.

Finally, as suggested by cgnieder, you could try looking at this post: [How to convert dots to commas in mathmode?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/97571/how-to-convert-dots-to-commas-in-mathmode)

Comment: `siunit` seems to be great for many uses. However, for only decimal comma `\num{12.34}` does not feel much better than `12{,}34`.

Comment: If that is the case, then why not writing it directly?  You can write 12.34 and 12,34

Comment: @MarioS.E. the spacing in `$12,34$` will be wrong if you campare to `$12{,}34$`

Comment: @MarioS.E.Sorry, does not work. With `\usepackage[spanish,finnish]{babel}` (and `\decimalcomma`) I got dot, not comma. With `\usepackage[finnish,spanish]{babel}` I got comma, but also wrong `\contentsname`.

Comment: The thing is `finnish` option is redefining the decimal separator.  The `spanish` option cannot pass the `\decimalcomma` command to `finnish`.  I read the whole Spanish Babel and it doesn't mention how to "export" this feature, so most likely there must be a way to change this within the `finnish` option. I found some documentation regarding finnish and babel (ftp://ftp.di.uminho.pt/pub/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/babel-contrib/finnish/finnish.pdf) but it doesn't go over comma. I would suggest you stick with the other options (`siunitx` package or `\matcode' changes)  mentioned in my answer

Comment: @MarioS.E.OK, I marked this as answered. I have never looked at code of babel package, so maybe I'n not going to look how babel-spanish makes it.