# Automatic italian decimal separation in $$

Tags: math-mode, siunitx

is there a way to set automaticly comma-decimal separator in latex in the "environment" $$ ? I mean having a 1,23 instead 1.23 by typing $1.23$. I tried to set by my own without any success, by inserting

```
 \sisetup{output-decimal-marker={,}}.
```

But it didn't work. Any ideas? Thank you

Comment: If you always write `$\num{1.23}$` instead of `$1.23$` that would happen with the setting you have, but I assume that is not really an option for you?

Comment: I use \num{123456} for large numbers, but doing it for all of the $1.23$ it's an heavy work. I should consider to keep it as it is, if it's not possible. Thanks for the help.

Comment: I guess with a bit of RegEx-search-and-replace it should be doable. Not that I would recommend it, but you could try ``\mathcode`\.="8000
{\catcode`\.=13 \expandafter }\expandafter 
  \newcommand\noexpand.{{,}}`` or ``\mathcode`\.="8000
\begingroup
\catcode`\.=13
\gdef.{{,}}
\endgroup``

Comment: Even better: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/97571/35864

Comment: have you consulted the `siunitx` manual about Localisation?

Comment: I tried with moewe answer and it worked. thanks

Comment: It' s not a duplicate becouse I have ,,, instead of ... in equation environment, how to fix it? with \dots doesn't seem working well.